# Calling a C# method, and make it take 10 seconds to return

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, multithreading

From a web service (WCF), I want an endpoint to take 10 seconds to finish.

Is there a way I can do a `thread.sleep(10);` on the method?

Comment: System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);

Comment: Please clarify your question - why wouldn't you be able to just make your method sleep?

Comment: I can't seem to find the Thread method, let me fully qualify it sorry!

Comment: Thread is not a method, it's a class in the System.Threading namespace, as shown by Arjan in the first comment. Sleep is a static method on the Thread class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could create a wrapper method which does the appropriate sleep.

```
Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
```

Comment: Just note that this wills leep roughly 10seconds. The Sleep timer precision can be multiple thread slices ~50ms on slower machines.

Answer (score 3):

Start a new thread that sleeps for 10 sec, then return, that way the time that the methos takes to run won't add to the 10 seconds

```
using System.Threading;

public static WCF(object obj) 
    {
        Thread newThread = 
            new Thread(new ThreadStart(Work));
        newThread.Start();

        //do method here

        newThread.Join();
        return obj;

    }

    static void Work()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean without changing the code on the other (Server-side) end of the WCF call, (since if you can change the code there then the answer is obvious),

then no..

Answer (score 0):

If this is just for testing, you could have the proxy class point to a web proxy that simulates the timeout. Using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/) you could script the request/response to be delayed by 10 seconds and then have the proxy class use Fiddler to make web service requests by setting the "Proxy" property:

```
IWebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("http://localhost:8888", true);
webService.Proxy = proxy;
```